# How to find average of a array column based on index in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, hive, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have data as shown below

```
-----------------------------
place  | key        | weights
----------------------------
amazon | lion       | [ 34, 23, 56 ]
north  | bear       | [ 90, 45]
amazon | lion       | [ 38, 30, 50 ]
amazon | bear       | [ 45 ]
amazon | bear       | [ 40 ]
```

I trying to get the result like below

```
-----------------------------
place  | key        | average
----------------------------
amazon | lion1      | 36.0      #(34 + 38)/2
amazon | lion2      | 26.5      #(23 + 30)/2
amazon | lion3      | 53.0      #(50 + 56)/2
north  | bear1      | 90        #(90)/1
north  | bear2      | 45        #(45)/1
amazon | bear1      | 42.5      #(45 + 40)/2
```

I get the point that first I have to do a groupby on columns `place` and `key`, and then I have to take average on array elements based on indexes.
For example lion1 is 1st index element in arrays `[ 34, 23, 56 ]` and `[ 38, 30, 50 ]`.

I already has a solution using `posexplode`, but the problem is in real data `weights` array column size is very high, as `posexplode` adds more rows, data size has increased enormously from 10 million rows to 1.2 billion and unable to compute in a reliable time on present cluster.

I think it is better to add more columns than rows and then unpivot the columns, but I have no idea how to achieve that using pyspark or spark SQL 2.2.1 .

Answer (score 1):

You can find max number of elements in an array column by [functions.size()](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.size) and then expand that column:

1. setup the data

   ```
   from pyspark.sql import functions as F

   df = spark.createDataFrame([    
         ('amazon', 'lion', [ 34, 23, 56 ])
       , ('north',  'bear', [ 90, 45])
       , ('amazon', 'lion', [ 38, 30, 50 ])
       , ('amazon', 'bear', [ 45 ])    
       , ('amazon', 'bear', [ 40 ])
   ], ['place', 'key', 'average'])
   ```
2. Find the max number of elements in the array field 'average'

   ```
   n = df.select(F.max(F.size('average')).alias('n')).first().n

   >>> n
   3
   ```
3. Convert array column into n-columns

   ```
   df1 = df.select('place', 'key', *[F.col('average')[i].alias('val_{}'.format(i+1)) for i in range(n)])

   >>> df1.show()
   +------+----+-----+-----+-----+
   | place| key|val_1|val_2|val_3|
   +------+----+-----+-----+-----+
   |amazon|lion|   34|   23|   56|
   | north|bear|   90|   45| null|
   |amazon|lion|   38|   30|   50|
   |amazon|bear|   45| null| null|
   |amazon|bear|   40| null| null|
   +------+----+-----+-----+-----+
   ```
4. Calculate the mean aggregation on the new columns

   ```
   df2 = df1.groupby('place', 'key').agg(*[ F.mean('val_{}'.format(i+1)).alias('average_{}'.format(i+1)) for i in range(n)])

   >>> df2.show()
   +------+----+---------+---------+---------+
   | place| key|average_1|average_2|average_3|
   +------+----+---------+---------+---------+
   |amazon|bear|     42.5|     null|     null|
   | north|bear|     90.0|     45.0|     null|
   |amazon|lion|     36.0|     26.5|     53.0|
   +------+----+---------+---------+---------+
   ```
5. Unpivot the columns using select + union + reduce

   ```
   from functools import reduce

   df_new = reduce(lambda x,y: x.union(y), [
       df2.select('place', F.concat('key', F.lit(i+1)).alias('key'), F.col('average_{}'.format(i+1)).alias('average')) \
          .dropna(subset=['average']) for i in range(n)
   ])

   >>> df_new.show()
   +------+-----+-------+
   | place|  key|average|
   +------+-----+-------+
   |amazon|bear1|   42.5|
   | north|bear1|   90.0|
   |amazon|lion1|   36.0|
   | north|bear2|   45.0|
   |amazon|lion2|   26.5|
   |amazon|lion3|   53.0|
   +------+-----+-------+
   ```

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution, one problem I noticed is if `n` value is 252 and number of partitions are 12 then number of tasks created are very high around 54270 with 257 stages. I think it is because of union operation which runs 252 times and slow downs the entire process. Is there a better way to unpivot the data.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to merge all the `array`s for a given place,key combination into an array. On this array of arrays, you can use a `udf` which computes the desired average and finally `posexplode` to get the desired result.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import collect_list,udf,posexplode,concat
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType,DoubleType

#Grouping by place,key to get an array of arrays
grouped_df = df.groupBy(df.place,df.key).agg(collect_list(df.weights).alias('all_weights'))

#Define UDF
zip_mean = udf(lambda args: [sum(i)/len(i) for i in zip(*args)],ArrayType(DoubleType()))

#Apply UDF on the array of array column
res = grouped_df.select('*',zip_mean(grouped_df.all_weights).alias('average'))

#POS explode to explode the average values and get the position for key concatenation
res = res.select('*',posexplode(res.average))

#Final result
res.select(res.place,concat(res.key,res.pos+1).alias('key'),res.col).show()
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution, is there turn around the UDF, I tried to check with some hive functions but I found nothing that can do zip function in python.Thank you once again.

Comment: May I know the reason for down voting for this solution, because I am thinking to consider it, as after doing bench-marking for two solutions, this solution ran in 26mins where another solution ran in 36 mins for 4GB data, however this solution has more shuffle memory spill.